# Silverlight "conditional" binding to a datagrid column?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I'm programmatically setting up my datagrid columns for my datagrid, then binding the grid to an observable collection.

A couple of my columns are bound to DateTime properties, however, if they're null values in the database, it's setting the DateTime properties to the min value due to DateTime being a non nullable type.

My binding is as follows for the aforementioned columns:

```
DataGridTextColumn scanned = new DataGridTextColumn();
scanned.Header = "Scanned";
scanned.Binding = new Binding("DateScanned");
dataGrid.Columns.Add(scanned);
```

"DateScanned" being the datetime property.
Now, instead of those values displaying in the grid as "1/1/0001", I'd prefer it if they were blanked out.
Herein lies my question.

Can I set this binding up to be conditional somehow and if the property value is "1/1/0001", display nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to convert specific values like that to blank or whatever else you want.

Comment: Haha, thx, I was in the process of writing my findings and posted 26 seconds after you did. I ended up doing what you've suggested so I'll mark yours as the answer. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Converter in order to convert from you ModelView to View the data in format you want. Have a look on this simple tutorial :

[Converter in Silverlight](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found out about binding converters. Wrote a "MinDateConverter" that checks if it's the min date time. If it is, it returns blank, otherwise it returns the datetime.

```
public class MinDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public MinDateConverter()
    {
    }

    public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;
        if (dt.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
            return string.Empty;
        else
            return dt.ToShortDateString();
    }

    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```